# Converting an Excel LINEST function to T-SQL or SSRS

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm stuck on this one...

...we're using linear regression for some trending and forecasting and I'm having to query data, create a dataset, then paste into excel and apply a linest function to my data. Since the data requirements have changed daily, this has become a very cumbersome thing to whip together. I'd want SQL Server to take care of that processing as this will be an automated forecast that I do not want to touch after I hand it over to an end user. When they refresh the data, I want it to refresh the linest function.

Here's some sample data

The [JanTrend] is a logarithmic trend in Excel that takes the trend of the Jan-12, Jan-13, and Jan-14 fields and calculates.

Here's that function in Excel

```
=LINEST([Jan-12]:[Jan-14]^{1})
```

The Forecasted field is basically [Jan-14] + [JanTrend].

```
StockCode   Jan-12  Jan-13  Jan-14  JanTrend   Forecasted

300168           2       3      11        5           16
300169           1       4       3        1            4
```

The JanTrend field is where my linest function is located in my excel spreadsheet.

I want to convert the above function to T-SQL or in an SSRS report. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I'm trying to calculate a logarithmic trend. I made some changes to my sample data to makes things more clear.

Comment: If you explain how the `Linest` calculates it's value it will be easy to convert it into the `sql` or ``expression`

Comment: It takes the Jan-12, Jan-13, and Jan-14 values and tries to calculate a logarithmic trendline. My apologies, I should have noted that.

Answer (score 0):

the linest excel function is just linear regression. it's (still) not available in sql server, but you will find a lot of examples of UDF's or queries implementing it. just google for "sqlserver udf linear regression" or refer to this previous question.
[Are there any Linear Regression Function in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536895/are-there-any-linear-regression-function-in-sql-server)

udf's are generally slow, so you might want to go with the solution in the third post in this forum. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic710626-338-1.aspx